# Scan an area of a web page's source code for changes while reporting it?

Tags: html, automation, console, web-scraping

this is one heck of a confusing question to ask so here it goes. Firstly, I'm not asking you to write me any code I just need help going in the right direction for what I'm trying to achieve here. Basically the task is this, I want to scan a select area of a web page's source code for changes and if something *does* change, I want to report it somewhere (like a console or something). However, I do not want just a notification of change, I also want what the change is/was. I've been looking into things like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) but I am still struggling to even find out what this is called.

Any pointers would be insanely appreciated. Thanks, Optimistic.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to capture a copy of all the files that go into a web page and then periodically grab a fresh copy of those files and diff them with the previously saved snapshot.  Since everything in the HTML, CSS and JS files is text, you can just use a text diff to report the differences.

Comment: Close but I need a specific part of the source code that changes just from one page that is a javascript line. I'm not looking for changes in the actual page's view, just in this one part of the javascript. I do appreciate the help though. @jfriend00

Comment: So, do the same thing for just one file from the site and look for a change in the diff for that one specific line or don't even use a diff, just fine that one specific line and see if it changed.  What kind of an answer are you expecting here?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, I want to find a specific line and see if it changed. I am wondering what steps I could go to to do this, like do you have a direction you could point me in?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps assuming this is from a node.js project:

1. Get the URL for the specific script file you're looking for a change in.
2. Using the `request()` module, fetch that URL.
3. Break the data up into lines (probably using `.split()`).
4. Find the specific line you are looking for either by counting line numbers of by searching for some representative text in that line.
5. Using some sort of search in that line (perhaps a regex), find the current value of the exact item in that line you are looking for.
6. Save the current value.
7. Then, at some future time, repeat this whole process and compare what you find to the previous value.

If this is being done from a browser instead of node.js, then use an Ajax call to retrieve the file.  If the file is on another domain from your web page and that domain does not permit cross-origin requests, then you cannot solve this problem in an automated fashion from a browser in your own web page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it with Jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

String scriptCssQuery = "script"; // Tune this CSS query to find THE script you need.

Element script = doc.select(scriptCssQuery).first();
if (script != null) {
   String scriptLines = script.html();

   // Store the changing line somewhere and compare it to its previous value...
}
```